# getting data from pdf file using ElasticSearch / Symfony

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin, symfony-2.8

actually i'm using Symfony and i have integrated ElasticSearch , 
I want to extract data from Pdf file (name,age,adress)/ or text file in order to get a form filled with data how to do it  ?
Ps: I have configured elastic.yml i have added all the indexs , and when i have have visited 127.0.0.1:9200 i got my object successfully (json format) all i want is how to read from pdf file and retrieve all data

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pdf parsing library like https://pdfparser.org/documentation

```
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('document.pdf');

$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;
```